# Application crashes only on 2003 server only when some icon is used

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a weird problem, I think.

If I use a particular icon in my application then it will only crash on a 2003 server (32 and 64 bits); not on 2008, Vista, 7, XP. I don't get any useful crash info.

If I remove the icon or replace it by an other icon the application won't crash.

I prepared a test project (VS2010, VB.NET) with the "crash icon" which you can use to test yourself:

http://examples.sent.com/IconCrash.rar

Something must be wrong with that icon, but what?

NB: I tagged this question with VB.NET/C# because I can use both languages and this problem isn't language specific.

Comment: [Care to award](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/?cb=1) the bounty to @Hans, otherwise the points will go to waste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The icon contains a PNG image only.  That format wasn't supported [until Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29#PNG_format).  Not so sure why it works on XP, but clearly you'll want to make sure the icon is BMP based to stay compatible with old Windows versions.  Easy to fix with the icon editor built into Visual Studio, Image + New Image Type.